# Disable Snaplines in Windows Froms Designer

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

How can I disable the snaplines, when I move controls using the mouse in windows forms designer, which is shown in the image:

[image: img]

Comment: https://bluemediaboutique.wordpress.com/tag/eric-burke/

Answer (score 9):

### Temporarily disable Snaplines while moving a control

Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> key during moving the control.

### Permanently disable Snaplines

You can switch to **snap to grid** mode and then disable **snap to grid**.

- Open Options from `Tool -> Options` menu
- Select  `Windows Forms Designer -> General` from the left-side tree view
- Set `LayoutMode` to `SnapToGrid`
- Set `SnapToGrid` to `False`

Then press `OK`, and close the designer and reopen it to apply changes.

Also you can set `ShowGrid` to `False` to disable showing the grid.

More information:

- [Walkthrough: Arranging Controls on Windows Forms Using Snaplines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-snaplines?redirectedfrom=MSDN?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: This is a designer setting.

Comment: i am using above setting in my visual studio but it is not working

Comment: Close all designers and then reopen them. It is tested and works properly :)

Comment: I have applied but it is not working. When we hold the alt key It works but in designer window setting it not works.

Comment: How can i set it using the C# code Please suggest me

Comment: I think if you want to have a Custom control with custom snaplines or without snaplines, you should ask a new question. Also if you are looking for the way of creating an extension for visual studio that performs this job (While I think it's useless) you should ask a new question.

Comment: This post answers **Disable Snaplines in Windows Froms Designer**

Comment: Yes,  Reza Aghaei , I have Custom Form with Custom Controls using infagistic dlls

Comment: So you don't need to do anything else than what the answer says :)